# Where is the Topology Manager URL Configured for PowerShell Modules

Tags: web8, installation, topology-manager

I have installed my CM and Topology Manager on non standard ports. When I run the `Add-TtmCdTopologyType` command in powshell, it tries to connect to http://localhost/ttm201501, but my Topology MAnager is at http://localhost:82/ttm201501. How can I change this?

```
PS C:\Users\tridion> Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Id StagingTopologyType -Name StagingToplogyType -EnvironmentPurposes "Stagin
g"
Add-TtmCdTopologyType : Error occurred while attempting to communicate with Topology Manager Service at
'http://localhost/ttm201501'. The server returned the following response code: 404 (NotFound).
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Id StagingTopologyType -Name StagingToplogyType -Environm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...logyTypeCommand:AddCdTopologyTypeCommand) [Add-TtmCdTop
   ologyType], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdTopologyTypeCommand
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is an Environment variable called `TRIDION_TTM_SERVICEURL`

[image]

You can also add `-TtmServiceUrl` parameter to all your commands (but this is mostly used if you want to run Powershell script from another machine), for example

```
Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Id StagingTopologyType -Name StagingToplogyType -EnvironmentPurposes "Staging" -TtmServiceUrl http://host:port/ttm201501
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the fast response. Is this documented anywhere? I couldn't find it in the online docs!

Comment: Looks like it is not documented )